# fscanf usage in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file like this:

```
10 15
something
```

I want to read this into tree variables, let's say number1, number2, and mystring. I have doubts about what kind of pattern to give to fscanf. I am thinking something like this;

```
fscanf(fp,"%i %i\n%s",number1,number2,mystring);
```

Should this work, and also, is this the correct way of reading this file? If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each line with `fgets` (or `getline` if you have it), split up the line with `strsep` (better, if available) or `strtok_r` (more awkward API but more portable), and then use `strtoul` to convert strings to numbers as necessary.

`*scanf` should never be used, because:

1. Some format strings (e.g. a bare `"%s"`) are just as eager to overflow your buffers as `gets` is.
2. Behavior on integer overflow is *undefined* -- invalid input can potentially crash your program.
3. They do not report the character position of the first scan error, making it nigh-impossible to recover from a parse error.  (This can be somewhat mitigated by using `fgets` and then `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`.)

Comment: What is the harm of using scanf?

Answer (score 2):

```
fscanf(fp,"%i %i\n%s",&number1,&number2,mystring);
```

`fscanf` takes pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem with pointers, generally using spaces in the scanf format is a mistake -- in most cases scanf skips whitespace automatically.  So I would use something like:

```
int number1, number2;
char mystring[32];
fscanf("%i%i%31s", &number1, &number2, &mystring)
```

This will read two numbers followed by a string of up to 31 non-whitespace characters, all separated by any whitespace.  Note that "whitespace" includes spaces, tabs, and newlines, so it doesn't matter if its all on one line, or spread out over 3 lines or anything in between.

Note also using a limit on the size of the string -- without that, the input might overflow any fixed size buffer you provide (and there's no way to provide a variable sized buffer with scanf)

Comment: The `&` in `mystring` is a mistake: `mystring` by itself "decays" to a value of type `char*` (just what `fscanf` wants); `&mystring` is a value of type `char (*)[32]`.